# How to use PDF.js (pdfjs-dist) with Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am working on a svelte application that is using TypeScript. I wanted to implement PDF viewer like `pdf.js`. I really like this project, so I found an NPM package for it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist). I installed the package and tried to import 'pdfjs-dist', I got an error which says:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'pdfjs-dist'. './node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm install @types/pdfjs-dist` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'pdfjs-dist';`

I tried to install `@types/pdfjs-dist`, and went well but still facing that error. I don't know why. I also got [this](https://github.com/vinodnimbalkar/svelte-pdf) repo but wasn't helpful for what I was looking for.

**My Imports**

```js
<script type = "ts" >
  import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist';
  import pdfjsWorkerEntry from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you get this error? TypeScript compiler? IDE indication?

Comment: @johannchopin IDE, but because I am using typescript in my svelte app

Comment: Did u tried to reload your project in the IDE?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ isn't built in Typescript so there are no typings for it. This shouldn't be a problem if you allow it in your typescript project.

--allowJs works for me https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs